# Blazor - Manually trigger validation on multiple child component instances

Tags: validation, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a page with a model that has a list of Payments.  In the parent page I have code to add or remove payments.  When the page loads, there is one payment already in the list. This list of payments is actually a child control added to the parent page.

Parent page markup (partial for brevity)

```html
@if (NewClaim.PaymentsList.Any())
{
    @foreach (var payment in NewClaim.PaymentsList)
    {
        <Payment PaymentModel="payment" @ref="childComponentPayment"></Payment>
        <MudIconButton Icon="fas fa-solid fa-minus"
                       aria-label="Delete Address"
                       Color="Color.Error"
                       Size="Size.Small"
                       Variant="Variant.Outlined"
                       OnClick="@(() => RemovePayment(payment))">
        </MudIconButton>
    }
}
```

Parent Code-Behind

```cs
    protected Payment childComponentPayment;
    protected List<Payment> childComponentPayments;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    if (NewClaim.PaymentsList is null)
    {
        NewClaim.PaymentsList = new List<PaymentInfo>();
        childComponentPayments = new List<Payment>();
    }

    AddPayment();
}

    public void AddPayment()
    {
        NewClaim.PaymentsList.Add(new PaymentInfo());
        childComponentPayments.Add(childComponentPayment);
    }

    protected void RemovePayment(PaymentInfo payment)
    {
        NewClaim.PaymentsList.Remove(payment);
        childComponentPayments.Remove(childComponentPayment);
    }

    protected async Task ValidateClaim(EditContext editContext)
    {
        var claimDisplayModel = (NewClaimModel)editContext.Model;
        foreach (Payment payment in childComponentPayments) {
            if (payment is not null)
            {
                payment.Validate();
            }
         }
    }
```

When the form is valid, I want to validate each instance of child component, however, when the page first runs, the first instance is always null.  This is really where my questions lies.  I am not sure why it is null, and how to fix it.  The loop works and validates all subsequent instances as long as I skip the first one.

My child component is just a simple EditForm with 2 fields with validation(data annotations).  This is the code-behind of that component:

```cs
    [Parameter]
    public PaymentInfo PaymentModel { get; set; } = new();
    protected EditContext EC { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        EC = new EditContext(PaymentModel);
        //base.OnInitialized();
    }

    public void Validate()
    {
        var x = EC.Validate();

    }
```

This works exactly as I hoped it would except for the first null instance.  Can anyone please explain why that is, and how I may be able to fix it? Perhaps there is a better way to accomplish what I want to do?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker of mine wound up implementing complex object validation using

```html
     <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator/>
```

There is a lot of back and forth on this object in the .NET 6 but it seems to be  working for us.  I have not used .NET 7 or 8 as of yet and not sure if this is considered more stable for the newer frameworks.
If anyone has anymore input on this validator tag, please post

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a more robust registration process for your `Payment` components.   You're using `@ref` at the moment which is the source of your woes.

Here's a demo of a cascading registration service that you should be able to integrate into your code.

A simple class to hold the `Register` and `DeRegister` actions.

```cs
public class PaymentRegistration
{
    public Action<Payment>? Register { get; set; }
    public Action<Payment>? DeRegister { get; set; }
}
```

This is `Payment`.  It captures a cascaded `PaymentRegistration` and registers itself when it initializes.  It also de-registers itself when it's disposed.

```cs
@implements IDisposable
<h3>Payment</h3>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] public PaymentRegistration? Registry { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => this.Registry?.Register?.Invoke(this);

    public void Dispose()
        => this.Registry?.DeRegister?.Invoke(this);
}
```

Finally, here's a demo `Index`.  It sets up and cascades an instance of `PaymentRegistration`.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
<CascadingValue Value="_registration" IsFixed>
    <Payment />
    <Payment />
    <Payment />
</CascadingValue>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=OnChange>Check Registration Count</button>

@if (_registeredComponents.Count > 0)
{
    <div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
        <pre>Registered Components: @_registeredComponents.Count</pre>
    </div>
}

@code {
    private List<Payment> _registeredComponents = new();
    private readonly PaymentRegistration _registration = new();

    public Index() : base()
    {
        _registration.Register = this.Register;
        _registration.DeRegister = this.DeRegister;
    }

    private void Register(Payment component)
    {
        if (!_registeredComponents.Any(item => item == component))
            _registeredComponents.Add(component);
    }

    private void DeRegister(Payment component)
    {
        if (_registeredComponents.Any(item => item == component))
            _registeredComponents.Remove(component);
    }

    private void OnChange()
    {
        // click the button and put a break point in here to see the registration list
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for  your response however I am not following.  I don't understand the<CascadingValue> with 3 <payment> components.  This will change.  I have a + and - button that adds to my collection that in turn adds the component to the page.  Also wouldn't IsFixed stop from components being added?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `OnAfterRender/Async` Lifecycle method. The `@ref` directive only sets the reference to the component after it's been rendered. That means that during the `OnInitialized` method, the reference to your Payment component is still null.

```
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        AddPayment();
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

More details in this article [Blazor university component lifecycles](https://blazor-university.com/components/component-lifecycles/#:%7E:text=OnAfterRender%20/%20OnAfterRenderAsync).

Comment: Thank you.  I tried that before I posted and it still is null

Comment: you can try this method https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17361#issuecomment-558138782